# Convert file path to values in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have an Excel cell which takes a linked file and multiplies the results by a value stored in a different cell, ie: “Linked path x R4”.

Is there an efficient way to break the links so instead the formula shows `4.53 x R4`?  I have hundreds of these formulas, so breaking each cell link individually will take a lot of time. Thank you!

Example: '='C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents[Camps.xlsx]calendar_23'!$L$6*$r$4'

The value of 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Documents[Camps.xlsx]calendar_23'!$L$6' is 4.53.

Is there an way for me to have this cell read '4.53*$r$4' instead?  I know I can highlight the path and hit F9.  However, I have this for a large number of cells, and I was hoping for an automatic way to do this.

Comment: I don't follow how a file path (something like c:\Users\username\myFiles\ ) can become a value you multiply. Can you show us an example of the formula you are currently using?

Comment: Since there aren't any details to go on, I would guess that the link also specifies a cell or range, along with a workbook. In the above example, that cell in the other file has a value of '4.53'.

Comment: If condition permits, could you please share us with some sample or screenshot to show more details?

Comment: I updated with an example, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is quite a difficult issue when formulated in general. In Excel, you can easily break the links and get the current value in each cell with the link. However, if the structure of the formula is to be preserved, and only the external reference itself is to be converted into a value, then the matter requires a thorough analysis, because such an action was not foreseen by the creators of Excel.

The problem is that the links can be written in different forms in the formula, it depends, inter alia, on whether the source workbook is open or not, and the links can refer to individual cells or ranges.

This code proposal takes some simplifications:

1. One formula contains only one external link
2. Links refer to individual cells.

The included code checks only the active sheet, but after deleting the row pair:

```
If shCur.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then    ' only single sheet
…
End If ' only single sheet
```

will check the entire workbook.
If you're using the US version of Excel, you can use the `Formula` property instead of the `FormulaLocal`.

```
Sub Remove_Links_From_Cells()


'based upon https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/find-break-external-links-excel/
   Dim rangeCur As Range
   Dim rngForms As Range
   Dim shCur As Worksheet
   Dim psep As Integer
   Dim linkFilePath As String, linkFilePath2 As String, linkFileName As String
   Dim linksDataArray As Variant
   linksDataArray = ActiveWorkbook.LinkSources(xlExcelLinks)
   If Not IsEmpty(linksDataArray) Then
      linksDataArray = Application.Transpose(linksDataArray)
      ReDim Preserve linksDataArray(LBound(linksDataArray) To UBound(linksDataArray), 1 To 3)
      ' 1 - linkFilePath, 2 - linkFilePath2, 3 - linkFileName
      Dim indI As Long
      For indI = LBound(linksDataArray) To UBound(linksDataArray)
         'follow links' list
         linkFilePath = linksDataArray(indI, 1)
         'LinkSrouces returns the full file path with the file name
         'even if the file is open
         psep = Application.Max(InStrRev(linkFilePath, "\"), InStrRev(linkFilePath, "/"))
         'linkFileName - extract only the file name
         linkFileName = Right(linkFilePath, Len(linkFilePath) - psep)
         linksDataArray(indI, 3) = linkFileName
         'linkFilePath2 - the file path with the workbook name in square brackets
         linkFilePath2 = Left(linkFilePath, psep) & "[" & linkFileName & "]"
         linksDataArray(indI, 2) = linkFilePath2
      Next indI

  
  Dim linksh As String, linkref As String, linkval, rngForm As String

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  
  For Each shCur In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If shCur.Name = ActiveSheet.Name Then    ' only single sheet
     On Error Resume Next
     Set rngForms = Nothing
     Set rngForms = shCur.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
     On Error GoTo 0
     If Not rngForms Is Nothing Then
        For Each rangeCur In rngForms    'cells with formulas
           rngForm = rangeCur.FormulaLocal
           For indI = LBound(linksDataArray) To UBound(linksDataArray)
              'scan links' list
              linkFilePath = linksDataArray(indI, 1)
              linkFilePath2 = linksDataArray(indI, 2)
              linkFileName = linksDataArray(indI, 3)
                                      
              ' one link per formula
              If InStr(rngForm, linkFileName) Then
                 ' external link found
                 Dim br As Long
                 br = InStr(rngForm, "]")
                 If br Then
                    linksh = Mid(rngForm, br + 1)
                    linkref = linksh
                    linksh = Left(linksh, InStr(linksh, "!"))
                 Else
                    linksh = "!"
                    linkref = rngForm
                 End If
                    ' linksh ends with "'!" or with "!"
                 linkref = Mid(linkref, InStr(linkref, "!") + 1)
              
                 Dim chrset As String, c As Long, res As String, chr As String
                 chrset = "[0-9A-Za-z$:]"
                 res = vbNullString
                 For c = 1 To Len(linkref)
                    chr = Mid(linkref, c, 1)
                    If chr Like chrset Then
                       res = res & chr
                    Else
                       Exit For
                    End If
                 Next c
                 Dim res1 As String
                 res1 = res
                 If InStr(res, ":") Then
                    res = Left(res, InStr(res, ":") - 1)
                 End If  'in case of ":" only the first cell
                 If InStr(rngForm, linkFilePath2) Then
                    linkref = "'" & linkFilePath2 & linksh & res
                 Else
                    If Len(linksh) > 1 Then
                       linkref = "[" & linkFileName & "]" & linksh & res
                    Else
                       linkref = linkFileName & linksh & res
                    End If
                    If InStr(linksh, "'") Then linkref = "'" & linkref
                 End If
                 With rangeCur
                    .FormulaLocal = "=" & linkref
                    linkval = .Value
                    If Not IsError(linkval) Then
                       If Application.IsText(linkval) Then linkval = """" & linkval & """"
                       If res <> res1 Then linkref = "'" & linkFilePath2 & linksh & res1
                       .FormulaLocal = Replace(rngForm, linkref, linkval)
                    End If
                 End With
                 Exit For
              End If
           Next indI
        Next rangeCur
     End If
     End If ' only single sheet
  Next shCur
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Else
      MsgBox "No external links in the ActiveWorkbook"
   End If
End Sub
```